# Fluid Simulation, How to change the angle of the fluid based on the rotation of the inflow object

Tags: fluid-simulation

Right now, when I run my fluid sim the water only flows down. I know that I can change this angle manually using the initial velocity values on the inflow object, but it would be alot easier and alot more dynamic if the angle could be adjusted on the fly in animations, just by rotating the Inflow object.

Its simple on the face of it. If I have a plane that emits water downward, and I rotate it 90 degrees the water should now be shooting out to the left or to the right.

I have failed in all of my attempts to google this and im pulling my hair out. So please tell me, Is this even possible. And If so, How is it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea using the initial velocity is correct. Apart from *Source* and the *Initial X*, *Y*, and *Z* axes there is also the option to enter a velocity for *Normal*.

If you take a flat object like a plane or a filled circle and make sure you check *Is Planar* in the *Flow Source* options, then you can use the *Normal* velocity to point the inflow into the direction of the face normal. This way you don't have to make sure there is surrounding effector geometry sufficient to guide the inflow. Of course you have to set the velocity high enough to conquer gravity if you haven't turned that off.

The following animation uses a flat circle with a *Normal* velocity of 50 (to make sure it works against gravity when pointing upwards), all other velocities are set to 0:

[image: inflow normal]

Comment: Oh! Thank you I'll have to try that. I didn't realize that the normal setting did that, so I was only had it set to 5 but assuming gravity is something like 9.8 the I wouldn't have seen any change. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it's not only gravity, the domain resolution plays a role as well. In my example it's only 64, because I made it just as a quick visual demonstration. But if you increase it to 128, the water will not shoot out as far as it does now.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it use a sphere as inflow object, give it an initial velocity like 10, then put a cylinder as effector object around that sphere with a solidify modifier, then parent your sphere to the cylinder and if you rotate your cylinder you get something like this:

[image]