# Changing the impact angle of drop in liquid simulation from 90 degrees to 45 degrees

Tags: fluid-simulation

**Setup:** I've set up a regular fluid simulation with an emitter above a 'pond' and an effector to keep the "water" in place. (blue arrow in the image)
When I run the simulation, the drop goes straight down into the water and makes a nice splash.

**Problem:** I want to have the drop impact the water surface at an trajectory of 45 degress, rather than the 90 degrees default angle. (red arrow in the image)
How can I do this?

[image: different impact angles]

Comment: This probably has your answer.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244865/fluid-simulation-how-to-change-the-angle-of-the-fluid-based-on-the-rotation-of

Comment: Yes, thank you! I wasn't aware that this was the same issue when I usedthe search. But it worked great. I had to replace my ball emitter with a plane (the ball caused a spectacular water explosion effect), but the plane did just what I needed it to do.